# How to follow a link in QWebKit?

Tags: qt, dom, qwebkit, qwebpage, qwebelement

Having a DOM of the following html;

```
<a href="?op=order">
<img class="img_button" src="picture.gif"
  onMouseOver="this.src='some.gif';"
  onMouseOut="this.src='some_other.gif';"
  alt="" border="0">
</a>
```

how to follow a link (href) in QWebKit (specifically QWebPage).

Please notice that it's an image that is linked.
I can't do it (and I don't want to even if I could) by simulating a mouse click as I don't use QWebView thus I don't have the page rendered.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have the link's QWebElement in a variable called "link" (located through findFirst or whatever):

> link.evaluateJavaScript("var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent( 'click', true, true );this.dispatchEvent(evObj);")

(This is in Python, but it is the Javascript that matters. And yes, this is simulating a mouse click, but since it does not use coordinates, it works fine with an unrendered QWebPage.)

Comment: thanks - I found this worked in cases where this.click() didn't

Comment: For me the same, i.e. this.click() didn't worked (in some cases) but this did. Can you explain why that is?

Comment: @Albert In what browser do you observe this?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: In WebKit itself, not in any browsers. I uses the QWebKit interface.

Answer (score 4):

Using DOM's `click()` Java Script function on the element makes the trick:

```
QWebPage * page = ...;
QWebElement el = page->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("a[href]");
el.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have QWebView and don't care about scrolling automatization, this may help:

```
const QWebElement &element=__your_element__;
QWebView *view =__your_view__;
QWebFrame *const frame=view->page()->mainFrame();
QPoint const elemPos=element.geometry().center();
frame->setScrollPosition(elemPos);
QPoint const scrollPos=frame->scrollPosition();

QMouseEvent * const impossibleMousePress = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress,elemPos-scrollPos,Qt::LeftButton,Qt::LeftButton,Qt::NoModifier);
QMouseEvent * const impossibleMouseRelease = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease,elemPos-scrollPos,Qt::LeftButton,Qt::LeftButton,Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::postEvent(view,impossibleMousePress);
QApplication::postEvent(view,impossibleMouseRelease);
```