# How to click a submit button in QWebView?

Tags: python, forms, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have the following code (excluded class constructor etc) - I am using PySide btw:

```
self.view = QWebView()

frame = self.view.page().mainFrame()
document = frame.documentElement()
search = document.findFirst("input[name=q]")
search.setAttribute("value", "srbija")

button = document.findFirst("input[name=btnK]")
```

As you may have noticed, this is straight from google.com homepage. I am trying to basically search the page. But I can't figure out click the "Google Search" button. The documentation only mentions the `button.evaluateJavaScript("click()")`, but this only calls the JS method - I don't need any JS methods in this case, I need to actually click the button.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219880/how-to-follow-a-link-in-qwebkit

Comment: @HostileFork why yes, yes it does. So it was just the matter of replacing `click()` with `this.click()`

This reminds me, I really need to learn JavaScript... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to close this so it does not look unanswered... :)

Try replacing `click()` with `this.click()`, as per this question:

[How to follow a link in QWebKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219880/how-to-follow-a-link-in-qwebkit)